# What is the exact purpose of semicolons

Tags: semicolons

I have never quite understood a semicolon’s purpose in a sentence. I understand it brings two complete sentences together, but when should exactly I use it? Are there any rules I should know about?

Comment: We won't be able to help you here, but just as you are unsure, so are your readers. No writer in English has ever lost a reader for never using a semicolon. This "brings two complete sentences together" is not a good rule.

Comment: Have you tried looking this up online? Googling "when to use semicolons" gives plenty of results.

Comment: 'I didn't ask about semicolons; he did.' 'There's a good reason I don't ask about semicolons; nobody else cares.' 'There's a good reason I don't ask about semicolons: People don't know how to use them.' 'There's a good reason I don't ask about semicolons—they're fraught with danger…AAAAHHH!' I often use them for short, related sentences (they don't have to be super closely related; that's a myth) and use them as super commas (often before the conjunction) when joining sentences with multiple commas if needed for clarity/readability.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, that's not a good rule as written, because it's missing [the critical relationship criterion](https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/grammarpunct/semicolons/). But it could be worse: at least it's not an em-dash joining them. :)

Comment: @tchrist Yes, I am a fan of the punch of an em-dash. Like any spice, it can be overused—but I don't. A semicolon used correctly can still be fussy.